# Changes getting auto published to live site after some time interval when publishing done alone for preview site

Tags: publishing

We are using Sitecore 9.3 version having 5 websites. 2 websites are normal Sitecore mvc websites and 3 are SXA websites. We are using Coveo search.

We have 2 publishing targets.

1. Web -> Used for Preview
2. CDSWeb -> Used for Livesite

We have the below indexes:

1. Sitecore_master_index -> used for CM
2. Sitecore_web_index -> used for Preview
3. Sitecore_pub_index -> used for CD/Live site
4. Coveo_master_index -> used for CM
5. Coveo_web_index -> used for Preview
6. Coveo_pub_index -> used for CD/Live site

Recently we noticed that, when we make some change and publish it to Preview publishing target alone, after some time interval the changes were reflecting in Live site also. There is no auto publish job or publishing strategy to the Live site implemented. We are not using any workflows also.

Can you please let us know if anyone have faced similar issue/ what are the steps to troubleshoot this scenario?

Comment: Is there any future publish set or any auto-publish module installed?

Comment: No there aren't any dates set for publishing and auto-publish module is also not installed.

Comment: Is only that data publish which is coming from indexes or all data?

Comment: Did you check Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent agent in Sitecore.config file which is usually used for publish database periodically.

Comment: Please check your logs for Publish, root: null INFO (database pub) to make sure nothing/no one is publishing your entire Sitecore. Also, check if there is any connection between web and pub like replication or auto sync? If is only data from index that shows up on live, verify the rebuild strategies for all your indexes: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-update-strategies.html#intervalasynchronous-strategy

Comment: Hi @RamanGupta, Yes the config is like this->
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00">
<param desc="source database">master</param>
<param desc="target database">web</param>
<param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
<param desc="languages">en, da</param>
</agent>

Its only set to 'master' and 'web' which is preview. There is no live database 'CDSWeb' in the agent

Comment: Hi @SwatiGupta, I just checked and it's happening for all data. Html is generated from the renderings and there is no search involved.